C# Azure Functions Project cannot load/find any assemblies
I have a Visual Studio project (.NET Core 8, Azure Functions v4) which "works on any machine except mine".
The error message is:

The '---' function is in error: Could not load file or assembly 'X.X.X, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'. The system cannot find the file specified.

And it really makes no difference which package I import System.Net.Http, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates - it can't find anything at all.
Depending on which code I comment out and remove imports the message is slightly different:

Error configuring services in an external startup class.
XXX.Consumer: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '106f06bc-2885-4839-abfe-c23ed98b7b26'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. XXX.Consumer: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Other Azure Function projects work fine, but this one is "stuck".
Same issue in Visual Studio 2022 - Community or Professional.
I have read dozens of similar questions here and tried:

Clean and rebuild solution/project
Restart vs
Running Release vs Debug
Deleting entire Debug/Release Directories
Updating al NuGet packages
Opening my bin/Debug/net8.0/Project.dll in DependencyWalker (see below)

DependencyWalker is showing a gazillion "Error opening file." messages as well as:

Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.


UPDATE:
C# Project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.SchemaRegistry" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.3.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="4.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

dotnet --list-sdks
8.0.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

FYI: I installed .NET v6 later to see if it helped (since CoreToolsHost was logging "Loading .NET 6 host") but this did not help.

Visual Studio is the editor, not the project or binary. We can't guess what the actual project is doing apart from trying to load the wrong libraries, or trying to run on the wrong runtime. Please post the absolute minimum code that reproduces the issue and check which runtime is used by Azure Functions. The screenshot or the Visual Studio details aren't relevant. The messages simply say the libraries aren't where the project is running. Azure Functions doesn't run on my machine, it only runs on the cloud, using the configured runtime.

Right now it's unclear if the problem occurs on Azure, in which case the wrong runtime was configured, or on the development machine which means the .NET SDK is missing. What do you see if you run dotnet --list-sdks ? Please post that output along with the contents of your csproj file. System.Net.Http and System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates are core namespaces, so if they're missing, either the runtime or the SDK are missing

The issue is local and .net 8 is listed as an sdk. The project file lists dotnet8 as the target. Will post details in an update.

You didn't post the output of dotnet --list-sdks. Something weird is going on on this project and this machine. Millions of .NET Core developers have no problem with VS and the current Long Term Support version. Perhaps the SDK is NOT installed. Perhaps you have a global.json fixing it to 6.0. And that "Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="4.0.1" is really, really weird. That's a 13-yeard old version that's not used by anything

As Jon Skeet blogged just 2 days ago: No, the bug is in your code (and mine). Try following the guidelines in that article, which apply to any project and language. First try limiting the code to the absolute minimum. Eg a .NET 8 Console app that just uses HttpClient to get www.google.com. That would work everywhere. If it doesn't, there's a problem with your installation. If it does, try to create the absolute minimum Azure Function code with just that line. Does it work?

BTW the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script package was discontinued 7 years ago. Are you trying to maintain some legacy project? What do we have to install and do to replicate the problem? I'm pretty sure that if I install the Func CLI and run func init the project will work

Yes, as I said it is one specific project (unfortunately closed source) possibly written for older versions of Azure Functions which needs updating. I have posted a solution below which at least gets things running.

It doesn't matter if the project is open or closed source, you can always create a small example that demonstrates the problem, or post a code snippet. "Closed" isn't a legal term and neither patents nor copyright protect common idioms or prevent you from showing how you use third party libraries and their APIs - because that's also common practice.

Solved by adding the following line to local.settings.json:
"FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",


This doesn't explain how the problem (which is still missing) is solved. One can infer that you're trying to migrate an older project to .NET 8 though. Googling for that flag returns Updating to target .NET 8 among the results. Judging by the docs one can guess that you're trying to migrate a legacy project to .NET 8 without also migrating to the isolated worker model yet. You could have said all that in the question itself.

Interesting analysis. However, the project was and is deployed (with <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>) to Azure and runs fine in the cloud. The issue was on individual developer's machines where, for some, it runs, others (like mine) require this flag or else the func.exe wrapper looks for the wrong .NET Runtime. Your analysis may be correct if the cloud runtime ignores the TargetFramework and was running .NET 6 but, even if I installed .NET 6 locally, it would not run and brough the same errors.

We encountered the same issue while debugging an Azure Functions project locally. It had been working fine, but suddenly we started receiving the following error messages:
Error configuring services in an external startup class.
... Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****'. The system cannot find the file specified.A host error has occurred during startup operation '****'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. KnifConnect.Functions: Could not load file or assembly 
....

Just wanted to add these error messages in case anyone else tries to search for a solution to this problem.
The solution was as Marc mentioned:
Add the following line to local.settings.json:
"FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",

